# Put the Laravel Application .env variables in AWS Software panel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a Laravel App running in AWS and I want to delete the .env file and use the Env variables that Elastic Beanstalk has for security reasons.

Should I just put every variable in AWS, Or they are variables that need to stay in the .env file?

This is my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=
APP_ENV=
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=
APP_URL=

LOG_CHANNEL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
AWS_BUCKET=

API_STANDARDS_TREE=
API_SUBTYPE=
API_PREFIX=
API_DOMAIN=
API_VERSION=v1
API_NAME="name"
API_DEFAULT_FORMAT=
JWT_SECRET=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all of your environment variables into Elastic Beanstalk configuration.  Laravel loads a `.env` file but technically it's optional since it loads those values into the environment.  If those values are already in the environment then that's fine.  The Laravel configuration files attempt to load from the environment variables and not the `.env` file.

TLDR: Go ahead and place them in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration, it means you can change them easily without having to mess with your code.